# Ethernet port has no power when ATX12V1 power connector is plugged in

Tags: power-supply, ethernet, dell-dimension

I have an old Dell Intel Connolly: E187242 motherboard that had the power supply go out.  After ordering a new one and plugging everything into the correct ports, my NIC does not light up or getting any sort of power **except** for right after booting for about 1 second.  The strange thing is that if I disconnect the ATX12V1 power connector and boot up again, then the ethernet port lights up just fine, but the computer doesn't boot (after some googling I found that the ATX12V1 is an aux power supply for the CPU which would explain it not booting at all).

Therefore it seems like the power connector is somehow over-powering the ethernet port and causing it to shut down or something.  I am a Comp Sci. guy and don't know a ton about hardware, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the new PSU isnt dud, the board has been damaged. Mobo power comes from 24 pin, so adding that naturally should power the NIC (lights on like you say).

But if you then power the CPU, the NIC stops. That makes me think that one of the controllers on the board isnt working. Adding a PCI 10/100 card may bypass this problem for you, but being honest that board is EOL now and really its about time for replacement.